# usesEvenOddFillRule example for a donut with UIKit

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm trying to create a simple donut and add possibly a gradient inside of it depending on how it looks.  I've seen a couple examples using Core Graphics.  I was wondering how it can be done using UIKit with the usesEvenOddFillRule.  So far I've created two basic paths for an inner and outer circle and set the usesEvenOddFillRule to YES.  But the donut is still filled all the way.  Am I missing something simple here?

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = (CAShapeLayer *)self.layer;
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
UIBezierPath *outerCircle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 4, 4)];
[outerCircle setLineWidth:2.0];
[bezierPath appendPath:outerCircle];

UIBezierPath *innerCircle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 20, 20)];
[innerCircle setLineWidth:2.0];
[bezierPath appendPath:innerCircle];
bezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

layer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;
layer.fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
layer.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your `UIBezierPath` just fine.

Check out [`fillRule`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/fillRule) property of `CAShapeLayer`. You should be setting it to `kCAFillRuleEvenOdd`.

Notice that `CAShapeLayer` is taking a `CGPathRef` and not a `UIBezierPath`, and `CGPathRef` does not carry fill rule information with it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I can across it after banging my head against it for a while when my UIBezierPath 'donut' didn't have an empty hole in the middle. As @slazyk points out, you need to remember to set the fill rule of the CAShapeLayer, e.g. `layer.fillRule = .evenOdd`, even if you've set it in the bezier path.

If it helps anyone, here's a custom UIView class and UIBezierPath extension that does all the heavy lifting. It's IBDesignable for a bit of extra sweetness.

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    /// Draws a donut shape
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - center CGPoint: the center point
    ///   - radius CGFloat: the outer radius of the donut
    ///   - cutoutPercentage CGFloat: the percentage ratio of the 'hole' in the middle of the donut to the outer donut

    convenience init(donut center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, cutoutPercentage: CGFloat = 0.7) {
        self.init()
        let innerRadius = radius * cutoutPercentage
        self.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        self.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + innerRadius * cos(0), y: center.y + innerRadius * sin(0)))
        self.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: innerRadius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        self.close()
        self.usesEvenOddFillRule = false
    }
}

@IBDesignable
class DonutView: UIView {

    let donut = CAShapeLayer()

    // Cutout percentage - the 'hole' in the donut
    @IBInspectable var cutout: CGFloat = 0.7 {
        didSet {
            setup()
        }
    }

    // The fill color of the donut
    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = .black {
        didSet {
            donut.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    // The stroke color of the donut
    @IBInspectable var strokeColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            donut.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    // The thickness of the stroke.
    // No need to set other line properties as there
    // are no endcaps etc.
    @IBInspectable var lineWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            donut.lineWidth = lineWidth
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    // Common setup. Draw the donut and add to the view's layer
    func setup() {
        let radius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2.0
        let mid = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        donut.path = UIBezierPath(donut: mid, radius: radius, cutoutPercentage: cutout).cgPath
        layer.addSublayer(donut)
        // CAShaperLayer requires a fill rule of its own for paths
        donut.fillRule = .evenOdd
    }

}
```

Here's the resulting view in a nib file:

[image: Custom view in a .xib]